# Parse Links That Contain A Specific Phrase

Tags: php, parsing

I have this script.
I need is so that it only writes the links that contain `"/product-product/"` to the file `items.txt`. Well, not the wohle link but the 10 didget item-nr 
product-product/**1007687980**

In the example you see the item-nr is something with /100. I was searching for items in a category where the nrs are something with /100.  But that is no longer needed.

```
$keyword= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$site=1;
while ($site<30) {
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/?keywords='. $keyword .'&x=0&y=0&pagecount='.$site.'&sort=sort');
$html = $content;
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$urls = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

$lookfor='http://www.example.com';

foreach ($urls as $url){
    if(substr($url->getAttribute('href'),0,strlen($lookfor))==$lookfor){
       $tubeurl = str_replace ("http://www.example.com","",$url->getAttribute('href'));
    $tubeurl = substr($tubeurl, strpos($tubeurl,"/product-product/100")+17, 10);
    file_put_contents("items.txt", "" .$tubeurl. "
", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);// this line must remain, it makes it so that there is a new line  \n wouldn't work

    }
} $site++; echo $site;}
```

regex would be a solution. but I read here on Stackoverflow that is a lot of work for the server.

Comment: it's not that much work 99% of sites are littered with regexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple regular expression that puts your product ID into $1 should do the trick.  You probably want some more logic to make sure that $1.  Modified it so that $1 should always be 10 digits.

```
$keyword= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$site=1;
while ($site<30) {
  $content = file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/?keywords=' . $keyword . '&x=0&y=0&pagecount='.$site.'&sort=sort');
  $html = $content;
  $dom = new DomDocument();
  @$dom->loadHTML($html);
  $urls = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

  $lookfor='http://www.domain.com';

  foreach ($urls as $url){
      if(substr($url->getAttribute('href'),0,strlen($lookfor))==$lookfor){
         $tubeurl = str_replace ("http://www.domain.com","",$url->getAttribute('href'));

         preg_match("/^http.*/product-product\/(\d{10})$/", $tubeurl, $matches);



      file_put_contents("items.txt", $1,
        FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); // this line must remain, it makes it so that there is a new line  \n wouldn't work

      }
  } 

  $site++;

  echo $site;
}
```

Comment: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found in C:\wamp\www\scramazon\s.php on line 15

Comment: fixe sorry about that forgot the / at the beginning of the regex